# Scrolling and .addClass(); issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am working on a "one page" website with a fixed navigation and about 5 different pages inside the one document.

**UPDATED WORKING LINK**

http://www.coco-works.com/Archive/  LIVE VERSION

I'm having trouble with the active class addition.  When you click Keep in Touch or Home, the class is not applied. As you can see from the live version, it's not function properly.

The page works something like this;
[image]

And here is the JavaScript;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
            var op = $(event.target);
            var id = op.attr('href');
            if (id.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $.scrollTo(id, 1000, {
                    offset: {
                        top: 75
                    },
                    axis: 'y',
                    onAfter: function() {
                        window.location.hash = id.split('#')[1];
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    $.fn.waypoint.defaults.offset = 75;
    $('.section h1.page_name').waypoint(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var op = $('#navigation a[href = "#' + id + '"]');
        if (op.length) {
            $("#navigation a").removeClass("active");
            op.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not a strong programmer. I've tried to edit it as best as I can and I'm just stuck. Any insight to fixing this would highly be appreciated.

Still looking for an answer, below couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: can you link some live example? other thing: you don't need to bind the event in the `body` and look for the `targetnode` element. just apply a common class to the menu links and apply the function to them. for example: `$('a.my-menu').each(function(){//your function});`

Comment: well, if you add complete html(basic), then i wouldn't have to bother creating all elements or if you add specific code, and maybe someone with adept knowledge may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the waypoints plugin was doing, but I've refactored your code and it is working for me.  Note that I took out the call to .waypoints, and changed your $('body').click() handler to be a more specific handler on the navigation link elements.  This handler will scroll to each element and then will perform the removal and addition of the class correctly when the scrolling is done:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    function highlightNav(navElement){
        $("#navigation a").removeClass('active');
        navElement.addClass('active');
    }

    $('#navigation a').click(function(event){
        var nav = $(this);
        var id = nav.attr('href');
        $.scrollTo(id, 1000, {
            offset: { top: -75 },
            axis: 'y',
            onAfter: function(){
                highlightNav(nav);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() == 0){
            highlightNav($("#navigation a[href*='home']"));
        } 
    });


    $.fn.waypoint.defaults.offset = 75;
    $('.section h1.page_name').waypoint(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var op = $('#navigation a[href = "#' + id + '"]');
        if (op.length) {
            highlightNav(op);
        }
    });


    // Fancybox
    $("a.zoom").fancybox({
        'overlayShow'    : false,
        'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'    : 'elastic'
    });
    $("a.outside_shade").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'        : 'outside',
        'overlayColor'        : '#000',
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.9
    });
    $("a.inside_white").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'    : 'inside'
    });
    $("a.inside_shade").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'    : 'over'
    });

    // validation
    $("form").validate();

    // nivo slider
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
```

In the html I added a default active class to the first link:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#who">Who Are We?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Keep in Touch</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also I noticed on the page you have your css defined *before* the reset.css is called in.  That's usually bad practice you might want to make sure reset.css is always the very first css file pulled in.  It doesn't appear to have affected the page much but sometimes you'll get weird results doing that.

I made a jsfiddle of the results here:  http://jsfiddle.net/RNsFw/2/

the waypoints plugin isn't needed anymore I think.  I didn't change the fancybox or validation stuff because i'm not sure what those are doing and it wasn't really part of your issue.

I tested it in firefox and Chrome.  Let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: @nzifnab You kind sir have just SAVED my life! This is perfect, just tested it in the latest version of Chrome, FireFox, Safari for OS X and Windows 7. Works great in IE7 and 8 too. One thing, is it possible to have the active class apply if a user decides to scroll with their mouse? Thanks!

Comment: Oh!  So that's what you were doing with waypoints, I get it now :p  I added that section back in and made sure it was working.  It is.  See my updated code, and I updated the jsfiddle link too.

Comment: I was having an issue with manually scrolling to the top and it wouldn't update the nav location.  So that's why I added the specific `$(window).scroll` event handler for that one case.

Comment: @nzifnab testing it out right now. Thanks mate. I will just be a couple minutes.

Comment: @nzifnab Thanks bro. This is awesome. Bounty is yours.

Comment: @Twinborn I think you can't award the bounty until a day after you start it - not sure if it will automatically do it when you select this as the answer, or if you have to specifically choose "award bounty."  Check tomorrow to be sure :p

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vCgy8/9/

This removes the dependency on scrollTo, and the waypoints plugin.

```
 $('body').click(function(event)
         {
          if(event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
          {
           var op = $(event.target);
           var id = op.attr('href');
           if(id.indexOf('#') == 0)
           {

            destination = $(id).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, 1000, function() {
                var hash = id.split('#')[1];
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });

           }
           return false;
          }
         });

          $(window).scroll(function (event){
            makeActive();
         });

         function makeActive(){
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(y!==0){
                $('.page_name').each(function(){
                    var curPos = parseInt($(this).offset().top - y);
                    if(curPos <= 0){
                        var op = $('#navigation a[href = "#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]');

                        $("#navigation a").removeClass("active");
                        op.addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $("#navigation a").removeClass("active");
                $("#navigation a:first").addClass('active');
            }
         }

         makeActive();
```

Comment: In Google Chrome 10, your code skips straight from "Who are we?" to "Keep in touch".

Comment: Yeah our services, and features were just placeholders there was no actual content in the body for those I just used the OP's markup.

Answer (score 0):

This may be completely unrelated, but I had a similar problem yesterday - where, in the callback of an event handler, jQuery operations weren't being performed in that scope but if you threw the code into something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(selector).addClass('foo');
}, 0);
```

it would work - similar to how `$.animate()` functions (ish) if you call `$(selector).stop().animate()` without the `queue` param being `false`, eg:

```
$(selector).stop();
$(selector).animate({ foo }, { no queue:false here });
// ^ fail

$(selector).stop();
setTimeout(function() {
    $(selector).animate({ foo }, { no queue:false here either });
}, 0);
// ^ success
```

The problem, completely unrelated to the above example though similar in behavior/functional hack, turned out to be the method of binding - in my case I had been using `$.bind()` - but then I refactored this to use `$.delegate()` (`$.live()` would work also) and it functioned as expected.

Again, not sure if this related, but figured I'd pass that along just in case.  Unsure if it's a bug or just me not properly understanding some of the subtler parts of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your js code, but in your css/page layout.

Or maybe the problem is that you are using the waypoint plugin and you might not want to for this particular page. (As you will see you also have trouble hitting the "Home" waypoint again once you have left it, because of the offset you use.)

The thing is, the waypoint plugin won't trigger until the target element you are scrolling to is in the very top of the browser window, with respect to the offset that is. "Keep in touch" will never get to the top unless your browser window is small enough that the "keep in touch" section takes up the entire browser window (minus the offset).

You can see it visualized here:
[image]

[image]